# Facebook OAuthError - Can't post a public post to user's feed

Tags: facebook, error-handling, permissions, facebook-oauth

I want to be able to post to a users wall, (a message he edits). But if the user didn't allow posting on his behalf, then I get the following error:

> (#1) An error occured while creating the share|OAuthException

Then I read that I can ask for the permission again by sending him to my log in url again, but even after allowing it there it sends the same error.

Code:

```
try{...
     $ret_obj = $facebook -> api('/' . $user_id . '/feed', 'POST', array('name' => $title, 'link' => $redirect_url, 'caption' => $ptnr_fb_caption, 'icon' => 'http://...logo-small.png', 'picture' => $ptnr_fb_img, 'message' => $desc, 'privacy' => $arrPriv));

} catch(FacebookApiException $e) {

        echo '<div id="text">Error :</div><br /><p style="width: 365px;margin: 0 auto;">Problem authenticating via Facebook, please allow us to share on your behalf.</p>';
        echo '<center><a href="https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=<my_id>&redirect_uri=http://<mysite>/getFacebookData.php&display=popup&scope=email,publish_stream&type=web_server">Allow here</a><center>';

        //Send email to admin
        $subject = "ERROR Facebook";
        $body = "user email:" . $user_email . '| error:' . $e -> getMessage().'|'.$e->getType();
}
```

**Edit:**
I found that when I allow the permissions again (via the link after getting the error message), only the "everyone"/ public is generating the error, while only-me and friends do not.

**Update (@Axel Amthor):**

```
$facebook = new Facebook( array('appId' => 'app_id', 'secret' => 'removed', ));

//We got after the authentication request
$access_token = $_POST['access_token'];

$facebook -> setAccessToken($access_token);
try {
    $user_info = $facebook -> api('/me');
    $user_id = $user_info['id'];
} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    //return 0;
}
```

**Update 2:** 
Scope related code:

```
$red_url = 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=my_id&redirect_uri=http://mysite/facebook/getFacebookData.php&display=popup&scope=email,publish_stream&type=web_server';
```

It redirects to getFacebookData.php:

```
$access_token = '';

    $token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=my_id&redirect_uri=http://mysite/facebook/getFacebookData.php&client_secret=secret&code=" . $_GET['code'];
    $access_token = file_get_contents($token_url);
    $access_token = substr($access_token, 13, strlen($access_token) - (13 + 16));
```

It sends that access token to the tird page, (code in update: "Update (@Axel Amthor):").

Comment: could you paste the code where `$facebook` gets instantiated and initialized?

Comment: could you verify that this `$user_info = $facebook -> api('/me');`is working?

Comment: @AxelAmthor, yes it is, it returns an array filled with the correct data of my user.

Comment: What I'm missing is the `scope` parameter somewhere, asking to grant permission for `publish_stream`, `status_update` or `publish_action` - what ever you want to do? Currently, I assume, no permission is set at all.

Comment: For Instance look at this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/note/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing scope Parameter like (from my code):

```
$OAuth_request = _formatOAuthReq($OAuth, "read_insights,ads_management,publish_actions,manage_pages,publish_stream,read_stream,offline_access", $state);

....

function _formatOAuthReq($OAuthParams, $scope, $state)
{
    $uri = $OAuthParams['oauth_uri'];
    $uri .= "?client_id=" . $OAuthParams['client_id'];
    $uri .= "&redirect_uri=" . $OAuthParams['redirect_uri'];
    $uri .= "&scope=" . $scope;
    $uri .= "&response_type=code";
    $uri .= "&approval_prompt=force&access_type=offline";
```

In order to publish something on the users profile, consider these permissions:

1. create_event
2. create_note
3. photo_upload
4. publish_stream
5. read_stream
6. status_update
7. video_upload
8. email
9. publish_actions

As per `/[acctid]/feed` you are going to publish a "note" on the users wall identified by [acctid]. Actually, this is the user which has "logged in" with the access token given in the OAuth dialog. I've just poked in to our code over here and we're doing that with

`/me/feed`

and this is working like a charm. Actually it's not you who is posting to a "foreign user" but it's the user himself, taking your app to post to his/her own wall by granting your app the permission to do so on his/her behalf. Way complicated, I know.

Comment: The "/me/feed" fixed the problem! thanks :) (Put an emphasis on that so other users would have the answer shown right away).

Answer (score 0):

> I found that when I allow the permissions again (via the link after getting the error message), only the "everyone"/ public is generating the error, while only-me and friends do not.

So you want to *force* the user to post publicly? You shouldn't do that - let the user decide!

Maybe set "public" as the *default action privacy* in your app settings - then the user can change that to a more restrictive value if they like, either directly from the login dialog or later in their profile app settings.

And then don't give a `privacy` parameter at all in your API call, so that the value the user has chosen will be applied automatically.

Comment: I give the user a selection element where he can CHOOSE what option to input, when they try to select the public option it ruins the functionality.
In addition I already set "public" as the default.